# Fetch Real-time data using Riot Api? Is it possible?

Tags: riot-games-api

I am thinking about making an application that is run on a remote device (for example a phone), to gather and display data like:
Summoner Name, Health, Kill/Death statistics, how long am I playing this current game etc.

Is it possible to use Riot Api to get this data and display it while playing a match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can request data for current matches by using the endpoint [/lol/spectator/v4/active-games/by-summoner/{encryptedSummonerId}](https://developer.riotgames.com/api-methods/#spectator-v4/GET_getCurrentGameInfoBySummoner). For this you need the encrypted summoner id, which you can get with the endpoint [/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/{summonerName}](https://developer.riotgames.com/api-methods/#summoner-v4/GET_getBySummonerName).

The only real-time return value in this endpoint however is the elapsed time since the match started (gameLength). There is no other dynamic information.

Comment: And will it work in real-time? I mean using this endpoint will I be able to run match and fetch data like gameId mapID etc. during the play?

Comment: Yes, this endpoint is for active games, more precisely games that have started but not yet ended. Note, however that this endpoint is just a small subset of the much richer endpoint for finished matches. So you will be missing statistics like kills, deaths and similar.

Answer (score 3):

The [Live Client Data API](https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol#game-client-api_live-client-data-api) is a local API (https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata) that works with the game in progress, you can acquire the metadata of what appears on the game screen via this API.

There is also a [Tournament API](https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol#riot-games-api_tournament-api) to acquire info from all players in real time, but it needs to be a customized match, according to documentation with a code provided by Riot.